# "Update requires a valid InsertCommand when passed DataRow collection with new rows." when trying to update database

Tags: c#, database, insert, sql-server-ce

I'm new to databases and I'm facing a roadblock. I'm getting an error when trying to update my database.

Also note that my database is SQL Server CE 4.0, if that helps.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // Create a connection to the file datafile.sdf in the program folder
        string dbfile = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName + "\\userDtbs.sdf";
        SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection("datasource=" + dbfile);

        // Read all rows from the table test_table into a dataset (note, the adapter automatically opens the connection)
        SqlCeDataAdapter adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM history", connection);
        DataSet data = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(data);

        // Add a row to the test_table (assume that table consists of a text column)
        data.Tables[0].Rows.Add(new object[] { null, "Google", "http://www.google.com" });

        // Save data back to the databasefile
        adapter.Update(data);

        // Close 
        connection.Close();
}
```

This code's outline is from another question's answer, and I'm trying to test it and get it to work properly. Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to specify the Adadpter.InsertCommand for this.

Comment: @Nilesh thanks for the quick reply, and can you clarify what properties of `adapter.InsertCommand` I need to set? Thanks!

Comment: something like `var cmd = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)` this should automatically generate the Insert, Update and Delete commands

Comment: @Nilesh solved it for me! Except that it's `var cmd = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(adapter);` in my case. Thank you very much!